# Adding points to existing plot in R

Tags: r, plot, point

I have found multiple posts about this issue but none of them are solving my issue. I have an existing plot made in R where I want to highlight points of interest. I have a dataframe with the base graph and then a column with points of interest (y values).

what I have done is below:

```
print(points(x=which(df$base %in% df$interest), y=df$interest, pch=19))
```

So the column 'base' is the base graph and the column 'interest' are the points of interest. I am searcing for which X's in the base column correlate to the y points of interest and it should plot them. I get no errors, just a simple 'NULL' printed out.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `which` is just returning the indices of the points, not the points themselves, so you need something like `df$base[which(df$base %in% df$interest)]`

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Although now it is saying that the x and y lengths differ, despite them being both of length 2 in my first case. (tested with print length(x) statements)

edit: I forgot that base has two columns. I think I just need to make sure i am using the correct column. thanks!

Comment: If you try `ggplot`, there's `gghighlight` that is pretty useful https://github.com/yutannihilation/gghighlight

Comment: @Esther How do I make it so your comment was the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this trick helps

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
y <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12)
z <- c(0,0,1,0,0,1)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)

ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(z)))
```

I define an extra column for the interesting points in z. Instead of color you also may use size.
Peter